# Linux file ACLs are not kept using Docker for new files/containers created by Docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions, setfacl

I am trying to grant read permissions to group `grafana-cloud` to files under `/var/lib/docker/containers`:

```sh
#> ls  /var/lib/docker/containers/ | head -n1
0515ccad974eb0e4577c7b35a0c517ab889db95d996e6188e9d0377cfa2265d4

#> setfacl -Rdm g:grafana-agent:rx /var/lib/docker/containers
#> setfacl -Rm g:grafana-agent:rx /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Executing this snippet, it grants permissions to all the files and folders that already exists.

```sh
#> getfacl /var/lib/docker/containers/0515ccad974eb0e4577c7b35a0c517ab889db95d996e6188e9d0377cfa2265d4
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/docker/containers/0515ccad974eb0e4577c7b35a0c517ab889db95d996e6188e9d0377cfa2265d4
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:grafana-agent:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:grafana-agent:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

If I create a new file or folder inside `/var/lib/docker/containers`, the acls are correctly kept:

```sh
#> mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers/foo
#> getfacl /var/lib/docker/containers/foo
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/docker/containers/foo
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:grafana-agent:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:grafana-agent:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

The problem comes when a new container is created, where the acls seems that are not applied as I'm expecting:

```sh
#> docker run -d busybox
70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8
#> getfacl /var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:grafana-agent:r-x     #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:grafana-agent:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---

#> su - grafana-agent -c "ls /var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/"
ls: cannot open directory '/var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/': Permission denied
```

If now I run again the setfacl command, the acls are applied to the new container file tree and user can read the files:

```sh
#> setfacl -Rm g:grafana-agent:rx /var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/
#> su - grafana-agent -c "ls /var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8/"
70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8-json.log  checkpoints  config.v2.json  hostconfig.json  hostname  hosts  mounts  resolv.conf  resolv.conf.hash
#> getfacl /var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/docker/containers/70216a6debce117563d2273da01a1219edc9e1357864cde5026076548b7169e8
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:grafana-agent:r-x
group::---
group:grafana-agent:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:grafana-agent:r-x
default:group::---
default:group:grafana-agent:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

Is there something wrong in my process? It seems acls are not applied in first place as we can read `#effective:---` next to the `grafana-agent` user, but I could not find any
I've tried granting the acls to the users instead of the group with same results.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get this working? Or did you cave and use the cadvisor integration instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACLs only extend the standard POSIX permissions. The `effective` permission here is `---` because the POSIX permissions for the group are `---` and the (default) ACL mask is also `---`.

You could instead do the following:

1. Change the ownership of the directory: e.g. `chown root:grafana-agent /var/lib/docker/containers`
2. Set its permissions with the `s` bit such that all new files (and directories) created inside will belong to the same group which is the owner of the directory: e.g. `chmod g+rs /var/lib/docker/containers`

You may need to change the group permissions for `/var/lib/docker` too: `chmod o+x /var/lib/docker` (this will allow every "other" user to list files in the directory and thus to access the `containers` subfolder)